# FromBody and FromHeader mix both on model not binding all values

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, model-binding

I want to populate a viewmodel based on both Body content and Header content, I've tried to decorate with both attributes but only one or the other seems to be running and populating the value.

Moving the FromBody to the property causes the header value to be populated, having the FromBody in the param declaration on the controller causes the body Id to be populated.

Subsequently running TryUpdateModelAsync in the controller does populate both but this seems ugly and over the top.

Anyone have any ideas how to get this working?

```
public IActionResult GetAddress([FromBody]AddressDataViewModel model)
{
    if (!this.ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return this.BadRequest(this.ModelState);
    }

    return this.Ok(this.helper.GetAddress(model.Id));
}

public class AddressDataViewModel : BaseHttpRequestMeta
{
    [Required]
    public string Id { get; set; }
}


public class BaseHttpRequestMeta 
{
    [BindRequired]
    [FromHeader(Name = "sessionid")]
    public string SessionId { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Ever find a solution for this?

Answer (score 2):

You could try and make your own binding source. Haven't tested this, but something like a hybrid binding source:

```
public class FromHeaderOrBodyAttribute : Attribute, IBindingSourceMetadata
{
    public BindingSource BindingSource => new HeaderOrBodyBindingSource();
}

public class HeaderOrBindingSource : BindingSource
{
    public HeaderOrBindingSource() : base("HeaderOrBody", "Header or Body binding source", true, true)
    {
    }

    public override bool CanAcceptDataFrom(BindingSource bindingSource)
    {
        return bindingSource == BindingSource.Header
            || bindingSource == BindingSource.Body;
    }
}
```

Then use the attribute on your action:

```
public IActionResult GetAddress([FromHeaderOrBody]AddressDataViewModel model)
{
}
```

Again, haven't tested this, but I thought the code was a bit too much just for a comment. Please respond with your results.

Comment: hi, it does not work with our case:
`
public async Task<IActionResult> Search([FromHeaderOrBody] FooRequest request)
        {
            var response = await ProcessTheRequest(request);

            return Ok(response);
        }

public class FooRequest
    {
        public int Count { get; set; }
        
        [FromHeader(Name = "Origin")]
        public string Orign { get; set; }
    }
`
even we tried with `

                    options.SuppressInferBindingSourcesForParameters = true;

`